# A cycle $A$ homologous to another cycle $B$ is well disjoint with $B$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology

On Griffiths and Harris p.49, it says: Consider a standard torus $T$ and two $1$-cycles $A$ and $A'$, ... while a cycle homologous to $A$, for example $A'$, may be well disjoint from $A$.

I feel confused, because if $A,A'$ are homologous then $A-A'$ is a boundary of a $2$-chain, so $A,A'$ have to be connected (since the boundary of $\Delta^2$ is connected), then it's a contradiction from Griffiths and Harris. Where did I miss?

Comment: What kind of homology are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some intuition, which can be formalized depending on what homology theory you are using specifically. Think of the following blue $1$ cycles, and think of the boundary of the pink $2$ cycle. [image]

Comment: But the boundary of $\Delta^2$ is connected

Comment: The boundary of the pink surface is the disjoint union of the two blue circles

Comment: But the pink surface is not a $2$-chain, by definition

Comment: @6666 You misunderstand what a 2-chain is. It is given as *sums* of 2-simplices; the simplices only form a basis for $C_2$.

Comment: @MikeMiller One more question, but it's still possible for two homologeous cycles to be connected

Comment: @MikeMiller One more question, is that still possible for two homologeous cycles to be connected?

Comment: Why are any two homologous cycles disjoint? I think it's still possible for them to be connected